# How can I prevent a shower curtain from drifting into the shower's occupant?

Tags: bathroom, shower

**The problem to be resolved**

When taking a shower, the curtain sneaks closer and closer to my body and finally, it bites my butt, which is immensely unpleasant. One person in the household lacks balance due to medical issues and can fall to the floor on occasion.

**Special restriction**

Due to medical considerations, it's not possible to mount a rail on the floor. Whatever solution there is, it has to be above-floor concept. If absolutely nothing else works, it might be something that doesn't create a threshold or significant elevation.

**Solutions that won't work**

Installing a rail on the floor will stop someone in the household from accessing the shower. Fixed wall over a part of the access way and/or partial rail will create a too narrow access path heavily impacting on the ease of use.

**Schematics of the facility**

The bathroom has the shower part by the far-end wall, across the whole wall, not in the corner. The person stands/sits with the back to the wall opposite to the wall with the faucet. On the right side, there's a wall with a window then. On the left, open space with toilet and sink.

[image]

**Ideas for solution**

I was thinking about a much heavier curtain but I fear that it will still sneak up my donkey. Another idea would be a magnet in the wall that the curtain connects to. I suspect that the middle part would still "baloon inwards".

**The request/question**

What would be a nifty way to approach this matter? Can any of my ideas be set up in a functioning way? Anything else that I should consider? I'm trusting that there's a nice way to resolve it because people generally have butts and most of them shower.

Comment: How much gap is there between the top of the shower curtain and the ceiling? Is there an extraction fan in the shower?

Comment: There's the more expensive option of replacing the curtain with a solid glass door.

Comment: The fundamental problem is airflow, as you probably know.   But as someone who dealt with aging parents, I would strongly recommend not allowing your access-challenged person to shower alone.  Use a chair and have a second person guide them into and out of the shower.  Otherwise there's going to be a fall no matter what you do.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's about 30 cm but can easily be increased/decreased as the curtain rod is movable. What do you make of that? There's a small air outlet above the sink, in the non-shower part of the bathroom. There's an openable window inside the shower section.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'm not sure if it's an option. While the cost is hardly a subject (within limits of reason, of course), I'm can't see how the door would be installed. Partly, how it would be non-floor mounted. Partly how it would open and close to allow access. I'll post a schematics in the question showing how it's set up.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Kind words. Regrettably, it's not my elderly mother but a freakishly stubborn and unreasonably proud spouse with a disability. There's no way to persuade her into anything that isn't self-sufficient. Of respect to her, the curtain is as it is and nothing can't be installed touching the floor or blocking the access. My butt that is being snuck upon has a lower priority, of course. Never the less, it dares to dream that there a way to accommodate the diability requirements and unsneakiness of the drape.

Comment: Magnetic shower curtain weights attach to the bottom of the curtain and keep it straight

Comment: @KonradViltersten You could try changing the height of the top of the curtain. Either up or down might make a difference. Ref: [Wikipedia Shower-curtain effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shower-curtain_effect#Solutions).

Comment: @Kris How do I fix the magnets on the curtain to the floor? Are you suggesting a steel plate or something like that on the ground?

Comment: I fully commiserate with your situation even though we don't face any of the access challenges you do. +1 for an entertainingly well written question!

Comment: Depending on how much cost isn’t an issue, could you have the bathroom remodeled to not need a curtain at all?

Comment: @KevinMcKenzie My first thought was rejection because we can't set up fixed walls due to accessibility. But then, it got me thinking. I can move the water outlet inwards so that the flow goes towards the wall with window. That's a rather large operation but it can't be **that** expensive. ANd it's only a one time cost too.

Comment: My shower curtain has magnets built into it on the bottom of  it ( inside the vinyl, no scratching ). My tub is metal so the magnets hold to it. Also, leaving a small gap at the far side from the shower head allows for the convection of the air to come though the gap and NOT pull the curtain in.

Answer (score 5):

This is at least easy to try:  Go to a place that makes vertical blinds.  Buy a handful of the steel plates they use to keep them hanging straight.  Pick up some 3/4" diameter disk magnets.  Put plate on one side of curtain, and a magnet on the other.

If this works, then buy a can of that vinyl goop that you dip tool handles in.  Dip the plates into the goup.  This will keep them from rusting, and if they swing against the wall tile they won't leave a mark.

The weights are easily transferred when you install a new curtain.

If you have a delicate finish on your tub, you may want to change the style of your weights to reduce the chance of scratching:

Weights have beads of silicon seal on them.  Or use rubber drawer bumpers (See Lee Valley Tools)

Comment: Even pairing a dozen magnets with one on either side should do the trick.

Comment: It's worth a try. I fear that it might be insufficient to pull down the curtain by gravity sufficiently strongly, though. Your idea made me thing of the magnets or such but attached to a telescoping arm that's fixated to the wall. It would stabilize the curtain stopping it from ballooning inwards and be able to retract when not in use. Now, any suggestions on where to get such thing or whom to ask to make one for me?

Comment: @KonradViltersten if it's not enough, the weights aren't heavy enough.  It'll work.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this solution. My fiberglass tub is 25 years old and has been refinished. I don't want a bunch of metal bouncing around against it, wrapped in goo or not.

Comment: @isherwood In my case, it might be just the thing. It seems that most people have the shower in a bathtub. I have removed mine and there's only the pure shower where I have my feet on the floor. I love that way and I miss the tub not at all.

Answer (score 3):

Curved curtain rods virtually eliminate this problem. I installed one in each of my last two homes and consider them a standard thing now.

[image]

To prevent the curtain from falling out and leaving you with a wet mess:

- Horizontally align the brackets roughly with the inner face of the tub
- Vertically position the brackets so that, with your choice of curtain rings, the bottom edge of the curtain falls just above the tub floor

Note that you need good backing due to the potential for significant torque on the brackets. I wouldn't trust a mounting with just hollow wall anchors on both ends. One, maybe.

Answer (score 2):

[Shower curtain weights](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TJRN2G7)

> The weights for your shower curtain can help prevent from billowing on and keep it in place to get more shower space for you. You can position them on bottom or further up depending on what works best for you.
>   Features & details
>       •   Shower Curtain Magnets: The magnet is glued on the crystal glass, total 3 pairs (6 packs)
>       •   N40 Super Strong Magnets: Stick into each other to keep curtain in place by added weights, no sliding down even if used for double curtains
>       •   Fit in all Tubs: Place one on each other side of curtain and provide a strong grip to hold well, fitted in any tubs no matter what is metal or not(e.g. porcelain)
>       •   Portable & Reusable: Cary easily to use in hotel, home and others outside
>       •   No Sticking Together: Don't need to place them at different heights, no sticking together when closing or opening the curtain/liner
>   [image]

Comment: I'm going to order a set and see how it works out. It's only 20 buckaroos (plus some BS) so I can definitely afford to give it a go. Have you tried those yourself or know anybody who has?

Comment: @KonradViltersten  I have not use these but have used curtains with weights attached during manufacture. It is much better than non weighted. Fortunate I now have a door on my shower

Answer (score 1):

As another suggestion, you might look at converting the entire bathroom into a shower, in essence (aka doorless shower or walk-in shower).  This would involve a couple of things:  you'd need to make sure that water coming from the shower would go down the drain, so you'd need a very slight incline towards the drain.  You'd also need to make sure that everything in the bathroom could handle getting wet.  You'd also probably need to heat the area more.  There's also a lack of privacy, potentially.  But you remove the need for a curtain, and make it more accessible.

Comment: Fortunately, Swedish standards include the 2% decline by default. Also, the splash area is 100% as the whole bathroom is considered wet proof area. That's done by default already. Also, I have the floor heating installed, so I'm all good to go. I think I'll remodel the shower water outlet to come inwards towards the window, instead along the wall as is the case today. I'll try the suggestion with the weights first, though. Less work.